# SQL return all rows and number of references to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given these two tables

```
A                 B
id                id   a_id
----              ---------
1                 1    1
2                 2    1
3                 3    2
                  4    2
                  5    2
                  6    3
                  7    NULL
                  8    NULL
```

I need to return all IDs from `B` and for each ID return if there is more than one reference to `A`.
i.e.

```
result
B.id  more_than_one_reference
-----------------------------
1     true
2     true
3     true
4     true
5     true
6     false
7     false
8     false
```

For `B.id = 1,2` I need to return `true` because there are two rows in `B` with `a_id = 1`.

For `B.id = 3,4,5` I need to return `true` because there are three rows in `B` with `a_id = 2`.

For `B.id = 6` I need to return `false` because there is one row in `B` with `a_id = 3`.

For `B.id = 7,8` I need to return `false` because a corresponding `a_id` value is `NULL`.

I can see that for my purpose, simple `COUNT(B.id) > 1` check (for a given a_id) would be enough but I am unable to join this result to a `SELECT B.id FROM B` query.

**EDIT:**
I am also posting my own solution, since the accepted one wasn't working correctly when used with where clause.

```
SELECT B.id, COALESCE(S1.more_than_one_reference, false)
FROM b B
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.a_id, COUNT(B.a_id) > 1 more_than_one_reference FROM b B GROUP BY B.a_id) S1
                   ON B.a_id = S1.a_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way using window functions :

```
select * , count(a_id) over (partition by a_id) > 1 more_than_one_reference
from tableB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-`join`:

```
select b1.id, sum(case when b2.a_id is null then 0 else 1 end) > 0
from b b1 left join b b2 on b1.a_id = b2.a_id and b1.id != b2.id group by b1.id;
```

Or, using a subquery:

```
select b1.id, (select sum(b2.a_id = b1.a_id) from b b2) > 1 from b b1
```

Answer (score 0):

use an inline subquery

```
declare @tmp1 as table(id int)
declare @tmp2 as table(id bigint identity (1,1),a_id int)

insert into @tmp1 values(1),(2),(3)
insert into @tmp2 values(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(3),(null),(null)


select more_than_one_reference=(select case when count(*)>1 then 'true' else 'false' end from @tmp2 tmp3 where tmp3.a_id=tmp2.a_id)
from @tmp2 tmp2
join @tmp1 tmp1
  on tmp2.a_id=tmp1.id
```

output

```
more_than_one_reference
true
true
true
true
true
false
```